# facebook redirect

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I have a problem when using facebook authentication.

```
 <?php
 $user = null;
 try{
     include_once "fb/facebook.php";
 }
 catch(Exception $o){
    error_log($o);
 }
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
    'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
    'cookie' => true
 ));

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'publish_stream,email',  
    //'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/MediaEngine/304221192963546?id=304221192963546&sk=app_143090482526977'
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if($user){  
    try{
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $permissions = $facebook->api('/me/permissions');                                  
        }catch(FacebookException $e){                   
        }
       }else{
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
}
?>
```

When the user accepted the app, it will redirect user to tab page(http://apps4you.hu), user wont stay on facebook, but only 1st time will do that if the user close and come back to app on facebook(already authenticated) it works fine in iframe.
If I use the redirect_uri => my_app , it will redirect and redirect and redirect but never will work the app, the browser just loading and loanding but nothing happends.
I spent days to fix this problem but I could not find any solution.
Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change $loginUrl  as below and try:

$_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); // CSRF protection
         $loginUrl  _url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . APP_ID . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($next) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'] . "&scope=".$permissions;